# Hazelcast client connection setup very slow

Tags: java, hazelcast

We are using an embedded Hazelcast instance server cluster for incoming data processing. We have clients which produce ingestion data to the cluster.

Processing happens fine, but an observation is, that the client connection takes a long time (~1 min) to connect to the cluster. Specifically,

```
HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

Has anyone faced similar issue? If someone can suggest how I can try to identify the root cause, that will also suffice.

The connection works fine in local, (same machine), however, takes time in distributed. Can this be a hardware/network issue? If yes, any pointers how do I narrow down my RCA.

Using Hz 3.4.1

Comment: do you provide any server- ip address in client side?

Comment: @BilalYasar Yes. Using clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(addressList). Where, addressList is comma separated IP address without port. All are listening on the default port 5701.

Comment: @BilalYasar I am able to Telnet to the port successfully. Also, I tried to simply connect using a java client socket, and it connects fine as well. I was trying to narrow down any network related issue.